Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Producer Custom Error Handling
We are currently using @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "errorChannel") (global error channel) to handle producer-related exceptions, such as network outages or broker-related issues. We would like to implement custom business logic for different topics. To achieve this, we want to create a new custom error channel, specify it in application.yml, and process the errors accordingly. Alternatively, we can define a consumer for handling exceptions. We cannot use DLQ or any other consumer-related recovery scenarios because these flows require broker.
I've looked through the documentation and samples but couldn't find a solution. Do you have any suggestions?
Current implementation:
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "errorChannel")
public void handle(final ErrorMessage em) {
    System.out.println("** help me! **");
}

application.yml:
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        testTopic-out-0:
          destination: test.topic
          producer:
            error-channel-enabled: true
        testTopic-in-0:
          destination: test.topic

